# GWT update a celltable when database is updated

Tags: gwt, celltable

Is it possible to update a celltable when a database is updated automatically? or at least call a function to only update the celltable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the client side when the server is modified, you need to use a WebSockets library like [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). Otherwise, you have to poll the server with continuous RPC calls to see if the DB was updated (bad).